# Which of these commutation relations are correct?

Tags: commutator, anticommutator

I saw, in two different references, the following two commutation relations for the fermionic field operator:

[image]

and

[image]

which one of them is correct?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVg9e.png) "Stefanucci, Gianluca, and Robert Van Leeuwen. **Nonequilibrium many-body theory of quantum systems: a modern introduction**. Cambridge University Press, 2013." page 88.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Hjw.png) "**An introduction to the GW formalism**" International summer School in electronic structure Theory: electron correlation in Physics and Chemistry. June 2021 Virtual lecture, Xavier Blase. Page 39.

Comment: "which one of them is correct?" Why do you think one of them is wrong? You can break down that commutator in many different ways...

Comment: Anti-commute the last two factors in the second set of equalities, and they'll be identical.

Comment: @march I don't think they will be the same

Comment: They are! One thing you should note is that because of the delta functions, you can change one r for another in some of these terms.

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second expression is simplified as follows:

\begin{align}
\Big[\psi(\mathbf{x}),\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}') \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}'')  \psi(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}') \Big]_- &= \bigg(\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}') \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}'') - \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'') \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}')\bigg) \psi(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}')\\[5pt]
=  \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')& \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}')- \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'') \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}') \psi(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}')\\[5pt]
= \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}') &\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x})- \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'') \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}') \psi(\mathbf{x}) \psi(\mathbf{x}') \qquad (*)\\[5pt]
= \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}') &\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x})- \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'') \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}') \Big(-\psi(\mathbf{x}') \psi(\mathbf{x}) \Big) \quad (**)\\[5pt]
= \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}') &\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x})+ \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'') \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x}') \psi(\mathbf{x}') \psi(\mathbf{x}),
\end{align}
which is your first expression.

Here's an explanation for each step:

$(*)$ The delta functions are only non-zero if their argument is zero, so $\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}') \psi(\mathbf{x'}) = \delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}') \psi(\mathbf{x}) $. Similarly, $\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x''}) = \delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'') \psi(\mathbf{x}) $.

$(**)$ $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ and $\psi(\mathbf{x}')$ anti-commute.